# Phone book management in C

Tags: struct

Task:  to implement a Phone book management in C

What I did not understand exactly: I have to implement qsort to sort the phone book (lexicographically by last name and first name) which didn´t work although I used the syntax exactly as it is displayed on the web page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm

The error message:

> c:41:25: error: expected ')' before numeric constant

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char* vorname;
  char* nachname;
  char* telefonnummer;
} telefonbucheintrag;


void schreibe_eintrag(
      telefonbucheintrag* eintrag_ptr,
      char* vorname,
      char* nachname,
      char* telefonnummer)
{
  
  eintrag_ptr->vorname       = malloc(strlen(vorname)+1);
  eintrag_ptr->nachname      = malloc(strlen(nachname)+1);
  eintrag_ptr->telefonnummer= malloc(strlen(telefonnummer)+1);
  strcpy(eintrag_ptr->vorname,       vorname);
  strcpy(eintrag_ptr->nachname,      nachname);
  strcpy(eintrag_ptr->telefonnummer, telefonnummer);

}

int main()
{
  telefonbucheintrag telefonbuch[100];
  int32_t telefonbucheintraege = 0;
  
  schreibe_eintrag(telefonbuch+0, "Ada",    "Lovelace", "004917155669988");
  schreibe_eintrag(telefonbuch+1, "Alan",   "Turing",   "004917155669922");
  schreibe_eintrag(telefonbuch+2, "Ingo",   "Mueller",  "004917155669911");
  schreibe_eintrag(telefonbuch+3, "Ilse",   "Mueller",  "004917155669933");
  schreibe_eintrag(telefonbuch+4, "Stefan", "Sadat",    "004917155669988");
  
  telefonbucheintraege = 5;

qsort (telefonbuch, 5, sizeof(int), telefonbucheintraege );

}
```

Comment: Can you explain `void` in the last line of the code? Does the tutorial contain `void` at a call site?

Comment: Sry the voud was a shouldn´t be there

Comment: There are more problems than that. What is `sizeof(int)`? Why are you using it here? What the tutorial says the third argument of `qsort` should be? What is `telefonbucheintraege`? Why are you using it here? What the tutorial says the fourth argument of `qsort` should be?

Answer (score 0):

replace `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof(*telefonbuch)` or what you have